# Help embedding asp.net page in a Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-part, asp.net, sql

First off, I do not have access to designer, so I'm attempting this through my SharePoint site's on-page edit tools. I realize that this may not be possible, but I'll ask the question anyway. :)

I have an asp.net page that hits a SQL backend for data on servers in our environment. Is there a way to embed that asp.net in a web part?

Can you recommend a better way to query this SQL backend and display those results in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions here:

1) You can display the page via a Page Viewer Web Part. It renders as an `<iframe>` tag.

See [Page Viewer Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/page-viewer-web-part-HA010024045.aspx)

2) You might want to look into External Content Types and [Business Connectivity Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee518675.aspx), but this will require custom code. So if that isn't an option for you, you're probably best off sticking with option 1.

Comment: I like the idea of the Page Viewer Web Part.

Comment: Simple, yet effective. And it's OOTB.

Answer (score 0):

You also might be able to expose your custom page as a simple web service that returns JSON or Xml data and then use the Content Editor Web Part to add javascript to your SharePoint page that calls your service and renders the results in the page itself.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes this process [pretty simple](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/).